# Inserting Copied Rows Beneath Original

Tags: vba, copy, rows, paste

I have a cell in which a user inputs a whole number, in this case D4.  I then want to copy a specific number of rows and paste them beneath the original cells the number of times as indicated by the user input.

I have code that gets stuck in a loop where it just continuously inserts cells and eventually Excel crashes because I reached the maximum number of rows.  I'm trying to copy 4 rows and paste them 2 separate times.

The following is a copy of the code.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Range("D4") <= 1) Then
    End If
    If (Range("D4") > 1) Then
        Dim I As Integer
        Dim SR As Integer
        Dim K As Integer
        Dim NR As Integer
        SR = 6 'starting row
        ER = 4 'number of rows after starting row aka ending row
        NR = 5 'number of rows to inbetween paste operation and original
        For K = 1 To Range("D4") Step 1
            For I = SR To SR + ER Step 1
                Rows(I + NR).EntireRow.Insert
                Rows(I).Copy
                Rows(I + NR).PasteSpecial
            Next I
        Next K
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen some problems in your code, so I reorganized and edited it a bit:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim CellValue As Integer
    CellValue = WS.Range("D4").Value

    If (CellValue <= 1) Then
        MsgBox "Your value is too small. Please enter a new value.", vbOkOnly
        'Exit Sub would also work if you'd want that.
    End If

    If (CellValue > 1) Then
        Dim I As Integer
        Dim SR As Integer
        Dim K As Integer
        Dim NR As Integer
        SR = 6
        ER = SR + 4
        NR = 5
        For K = 1 To CellValue
            For I = SR To ER
                WS.Rows(I).Copy
                WS.Rows(I + NR).EntireRow.Insert
                WS.Rows(I + NR).PasteSpecial
            Next I
        Next K
    End If
End Sub
```

And for you to know, this code will be run every time anything changes on that worksheet (Worksheet_CHANGE). This also means that each time a row gets inserted it will rerun the sub. It would probably be better if you would put a button next to D4 which can call that sub.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  So another super newbie question; I received an object error when I ran your code relative to the Set WS line so I changed it to "Set WS=Sheet2" (I'm working on sheet 2 of my workbook).  So once i made that change and ran the code where D4=2, excel once again looped and eventually crashed.  Am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: Yes, as I told you, you still have your code in the Worksheet_Change event which will be triggered EACH TIME SOMETHING IS CHANGED IN THE WORKSHEET. Each time something is edited, each time something is copied and pasted. You need to relocate this sub and call it with a button or something.

Comment: Also I have changed the line with the Set ws in my code

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I tied it to a button and it worked exactly like you said it would.  Thanks :)

Comment: No Problem :) Just for the record: I would barely use the worksheet_change event because this really gets called all the time ;)